# Can I manage my team while trying to unlock the Free Rider position?

Tags: dont-get-fired

In order to unlock the Free Rider position do I have to be completely inactive or can I still give work to my team?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it from the Assistant Manager position and got it. You simply need to do everything last minute. Wait until the Work/Sleep bubbles turn green before you push them.

Comment: I managed to get this position but just once. I've been trying to get it again this way but now I wait doing this aaaaall the General Manager level for example and I don't get the Free Rider position, even when at an earlier time I got it easily. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be completely inactive.

Don't take any work and don't wake up your team. Just do NOTHING for a few minutes and you'll be labeled a free rider.

*Waiting until the last minute isn't a free rider, it's a procrastinator.*